# List of previous searches?

Tags: support, search

I'm trying to recall a previous search of a phrase related to ancient religion, but so much information has passed through my mind since, I can't remember.

Is there a way for me to view my previous searches?

I appreciate that previous searches might be available to moderators. However, are users able to access previous searches?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We do not keep a record of your previous search inquiries anywhere in the database. Thus it is not possible for you or moderators to query that history on-site.

Your best bet is searching your browser's built-in history. Most allow you to specify a partial URL (such as with `"stackoverflow.com/search"`) to find things in that history easily.

Comment: That's true, I've bookmarked it on my PC I'm sure. It's tempting to think about the potential of such a feature, a sort of record of development in particular subjects, maybe even shareable with other users. Interesting. Anyway. I see.